# How to show list of items in a popup dialog screen in Angular 6/8

Tags: c#, angular, primeng

I have a dialog and wanted to show list of items i fetched from DB. I am using [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog) Dialog control.

My app.component.html looks like this

```html
<p-dialog header="Available Titles" [(visible)]="displayTraining" [draggable]="false" [resizable]="false" [modal]="true" [blockScroll]="true" [closeOnEscape]="false" [responsive]="false" [style]="{width: '800px'}">

</p-dialog>
```

Using a service call, I am fetching data from DB and calling this service from .ts file.

My app.component.ts looks like this

```
import { TrainingUrlServices } from '../services/TrainingUrlServices';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TrainingUrls} from '../models/TrainingUrl';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   displayTraining: boolean = false;

   services: TrainingUrlServices = new TrainingUrlServices(this.http);

   trainingUrls: TrainingUrls = new TrainingUrls();

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

   modelDialogForTraining() {

    this.services.TrainingUrls().subscribe(data => {            
        this.trainingUrls = data;          
    });        
   }
 }
```

Where trainingUrls is my model object. My model TrainingUrl.ts looks like this

```
export class TrainingUrl {
  training_url_id: number;
  training_title: string = '';
  training_url: string = '';
}

export class TrainingUrls {
    Items: Array<TrainingUrl> = [];
}
```

My controller, TrainingUrlContoller.cs

```
public class TrainingUrlController : BaseController
{
    TrainingRepository repo = new TrainingRepository(null);

    [HttpGet]
    public string GetTrainingUrls()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        TrainingUrls results = new TrainingUrls();
        results = repo.Fetch();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);

    }
 }
```

The JSON it returns looks like this

```
 { 
  "Items":[ 
   { 
     "training_url_id":8,
     "training_title":"Desktop Apps - Date updated 3/27/2017",
     "training_url":"http://www.google.com?q=desktopapps"
   },
   { 
     "training_url_id":2,
     "training_title":"Implement Sequences Date 4/18/2017",
     "training_url":"https://www.sequencetraining.com/test.pdf"
   },
   { 
     "training_url_id":1,
     "training_title":"Programming guidelines Date 4/18/2017",
     "training_url":"https://programming.com/guidelines.pdf"
   }
 ]
}
```

Now I am trying to show the "training_title" in the dialog box. My code looks like this

```
<p-dialog header="Available Titles" [(visible)]="displayTraining" [draggable]="false" 
      [resizable]="false" [modal]="true" [blockScroll]="true"
      [closeOnEscape]="false" [responsive]="false" [style]="{width: '800px'}">  
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let item of trainingUrls.Urls">{{item.training_title}}</li>
</ul>
</p-dialog>
```

My issues are first of all, the dialog box doesn't show any data. When i debug the .ts file, trainingurls object is undefined even though there is data.

[image]

What Iam missing here.. It would be helpful if anyone can give working sample. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON returns a list of **"Items"**

> *ngFor="let item of trainingUrls.Urls">{{item.training_title}}

to

> *ngFor="let item of trainingUrls.Items">{{item.training_title}}

Answer (score 0):

One issue is I don't see `modelDialogForTraining()` ever being called. I'd recommend using the `| async` feature in your template. Example:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   displayTraining: boolean = false;

   services: TrainingUrlServices = new TrainingUrlServices(this.http);

   trainingUrls$: Observable<Array<TrainingUrl>>;

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
      this.trainingUrls$ = this.services.TrainingUrls().pipe(map(response => response.items))
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }
 }
```

and

```
<li *ngFor="let item of trainingUrls$ | async">{{item.training_title}}</li>
```

Comment: Actually "modelDialogForTraining()" is called from another label command. I am able to hit "modelDialogForTraining()" method. So its being called.

Comment: I tried your code. But it cannot find name "map". Is there any import for this?